# Describing an archive of blog posts (same domain)

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I have struggled to find an example of this online, let alone using `application/ld+json`.

The page contains a list of videos, a main content item, and lastly related news content (a list of video items). My site is similar to the news articles from https://www.premierleague.com/.

I have defined this as follows:

```json
{
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "ItemList",
      "itemListElement": [
        {
          "@type": "ListItem",
          "position": 1,
          "name": "my description",
          "url": "https://www.example.com/carousel-item-1"
        },
        ...
      ],
      "mainEntityOfPage": {
        "@type": "WebPage",
        "@id": "https://www.example.com/watch",
        "alternativeHeadline": "The title of this page",
        "description": "The description of the content",
        "itemListElement": [ 
          {
            "@type": "Url",  // this is the problem here
            "url": "https://www.example.com/related-news-article"
          }   
        ]
      }
    }
```

The issue lies with describing the last block of content as related news items. **How do I describe this?**

The news articles don't have all the necessary information to be [`NewsArticle`](http://schema.org/NewsArticle)s. The are simply a title, an image and a link. So I have opted to use a URL type. 
However that doesn't satisfy as a suitable subtype inside of `mainEntityOfPage`.

Can I describe it inside the `NewsArticle` inside of `mainEntityOfPage` (preferred) or do I need to describe a brand new `application/ld+json` block?

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schema.org doesn’t require any properties. It’s perfectly fine to use `NewsArticle` even if you don’t provide any property at all. But if you want to provide just a URL as value, you shouldn’t specify the type [`URL`](http://schema.org/URL) for this. Simply provide the URL directly with `@id`, either with or without the `NewsArticle` in addition:

```json
{
  "@id": "https://www.example.com/related-news-article"
}
```

```json
{
  "@type": "NewsArticle",
  "@id": "https://www.example.com/related-news-article"
}
```

Related links on a `WebPage` can be provided with the [`relatedLink`](http://schema.org/relatedLink) property, which expects an `URL` value. So you could use something like this:

```json
{
  "@type": "WebPage",
  "relatedLink":
  [
    {"@id": "/related-news-article-1"},
    {"@id": "/related-news-article-2"},
    {"@id": "/related-news-article-3"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.